# Are the field reducts of Euclidean ordered fields an axiomatizable class?

Tags: field-theory, model-theory

An Euclidean field is an ordered field $(F;+,-,*,0,1,\leq)$ such that every positive element has a square root. So, Euclidean fields are a first-order axiomatizable class. But, what about the field reducts of Euclidean fields, that is, the $\{+,-,*,0,1\}$ reduct of Euclidean fields? It is certainly a pseudo-elementary class, simply by definition, but is it in fact an axiomatizable class, and if it is, is it finitely axiomatizable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that in an ordered field, no negative element has a square root. Consequently, in a Euclidean field, the elements with square roots are **exactly** the nonnegative elements. This means that in the field reduct of a Euclidean field, the original ordering is definable as $$a\le b\quad\iff\quad\exists c(c^2=b-a).$$ And this means that adding the ordering makes no meaningful difference in terms of logical complexity. In particular, the answer to your question is **yes**.

(More concretely, just take the field axioms and add an axiom saying that the relation $\exists c(c^2=b-a)$ gives an ordering compatible with the field structure.)